# Xero invoice send email using standard .NET library

Tags: c#, xero-api

Here I have created my project on the **standard .NET library** to GET/POST invoices. But as I want to **email** the invoice to which it's being created on that name. Here is my sample code below to create invoice.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(string Name, string LineDescription, string LineQuantity, string LineUnitAmount, string LineAccountCode)
        {
            var xeroToken = TokenUtilities.GetStoredToken();
            var utcTimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
            var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();

            XeroConfiguration XeroConfig = new XeroConfiguration
            {
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XeroClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XeroClientSecret"],
                CallbackUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XeroCallbackUri"]),
                Scope = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XeroScope"],
                State = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XeroState"]
            };

            if (utcTimeNow > xeroToken.ExpiresAtUtc)
            {
                var client = new XeroClient(XeroConfig, httpClientFactory);
                xeroToken = (XeroOAuth2Token)await client.RefreshAccessTokenAsync(xeroToken);
                TokenUtilities.StoreToken(xeroToken);
            }

            string accessToken = xeroToken.AccessToken;
            string xeroTenantId = xeroToken.Tenants[0].TenantId.ToString();
            //string xeroTenantId = xeroToken.Tenants[1].TenantId.ToString();

            var contact = new Contact();
            contact.Name = Name;

            var line = new LineItem()
            {
                Description = LineDescription,
                Quantity = decimal.Parse(LineQuantity),
                UnitAmount = decimal.Parse(LineUnitAmount),
                AccountCode = LineAccountCode
            };

            var lines = new List<LineItem>() { line };
            //var lines = new List<LineItem>();
            //for (int j = 0;j < 5;j++)
            //{
            //    lines.Add(line);
            //}
            
            var invoice = new Invoice()
            {
                Type = Invoice.TypeEnum.ACCREC,
                Contact = contact,
                Date = DateTime.Today,
                DueDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30),
                LineItems = lines
            };

            var invoiceList = new List<Invoice>();
            invoiceList.Add(invoice);

            var invoices = new Invoices();
            invoices._Invoices = invoiceList;

            var AccountingApi = new AccountingApi();
            var response = await AccountingApi.CreateInvoicesAsync(accessToken, xeroTenantId, invoices);
            RequestEmpty _request = new RequestEmpty();
            //trying this method to send email to specified invoice....
            //var test = await AccountingApi.EmailInvoiceAsync(accessToken, xeroTenantId, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
            var updatedUTC = response._Invoices[0].UpdatedDateUTC;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "InvoiceSync");
        }
```

Now as I learned that Xero allows sending email to that specified invoice, here is a link which I learned.
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices#email

But as try to find method in the **.NET standard library for Xero** I stumble upon this method.

```
var test = await AccountingApi.EmailInvoiceAsync(accessToken, xeroTenantId, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
```

How can I use this method to send email to a specified invoice ..?
It throws me an error regarding **Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable**.

There is another method also in this library.

```
var test2 = await AccountingApi.EmailInvoiceAsyncWithHttpInfo(accessToken, xeroTenantId, Guid.NewGuid(), null);
```

As `Guid.NewGuid()` i have used is for only testing will add created **GUID** when I understand how these two methods operate.

**Update 1:**
Here is the method second method i used.

```
await AccountingApi.EmailInvoiceAsyncWithHttpInfo(accessToken, xeroTenantId, Guid.NewGuid(), null)
```

[image]

**Update 2:**
Here is the code i used.

```
        public async Task EmailInvoiceTest(string accessToken,string xeroTenantId,Guid invoiceID, RequestEmpty requestEmpty)
        {
            var AccountingApi = new AccountingApi();
            await AccountingApi.EmailInvoiceAsync(accessToken, xeroTenantId, invoiceID, requestEmpty).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I assume that both methods have return value of type void. Did you try to remove `var test = `/`var test2 = `?

Comment: @rufer7 as i have updated above its asking for requestEmpty .. ?

Answer (score 0):

The return type of method `EmailInvoiceAsync` seems to be `Task` with return type void. If you await the task, there is no return type which could be assigned to a variable. Remove the variable assignment and pass a valid argument for parameter of type `RequestEmpty` to solve the problem.

```
RequestEmpty requestEmpty = new RequestEmpty();
await AccountingApi.EmailInvoiceAsync(accessToken, xeroTenantId, Guid.NewGuid(), requestEmpty);
```

For an example test see [here](https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-NetStandard/blob/c4a053e1f90c87e1bd412f5761f3455cac92bf89/Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Test/Api/AccountingApiTests.cs)

**IMPORTANT:** According to the [documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices) (see section `Emailing an invoice`) the invoice must be of Type ACCREC and must have a valid status for sending (`SUMBITTED`, `AUTHORISED` or `PAID`).